# Multiple Animated Layers on GIS Map User Movements

Tags: carto, animation, torque

I'm relatively knew to GIS, so I figured this might be a smart way to go about this. I have a data set with multiple users in it I was going to use Torque from cartodb to show in realtime the movements of users simultaneously, until I found out that I can only have one torque layer. So I'm wondering is there a way to do this is cartodb?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. There is a new wizard option even further to the right, "Torque Cat", it will let you select different colors and styles for each of the users.